# Where is DbContext.Database.Migrate() method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, dbcontext, ef-core-3.0

I'm meant to call this method at startup but it's not reference anywhere:

```
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

> Type `DatabaseFacade` does not contain a definition for `Migrate` and no 
>   extension method `Migrate` of type `DatabaseFacade` could be found (are you missing 
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?

So which using / assembly am I missing?

Comment: do you have `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;? and please make sure you have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer installed if working with Sql Server Db

Comment: https://whatibroke.com/2020/03/25/databasefacade-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-migrate-and-no-accessible-extension-method-migrate-eshoponcontainers/

Answer (score 10):

I needed to add the following dependencies via NuGet.

```cs
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Comment: Indeed! It's seemingly in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore namespace (it's enough to import this one), but it's in the Microsoft.EntitiyFrameworkCore.SqlServer nuget package.

Answer (score 5):

Just import `EntityFrameworkCore` by typing the following at the top:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var migrator = dbContext.Database.GetService<IMigrator>();
await migrator.MigrateAsync("targetMigration", cancellationToken);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I cannot Tell you how thankful I am that you left this comment. It was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

(For.Net Core) After adding the package (Oracle/SQLServer)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5es8a.png)

you can design the startup.cs like this using extensions.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app
        .UseSwaggerUI()
        .UseRouting()
        .UseCors(options => options
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod())
        .UseAuthentication()
        .UseAuthorization()
        .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        })
        .ApplyMigrations();
}
```

So you can call ApplyMigrations as below.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace SocialRebate.WebApi.Infrastructure.Extensions
{
    public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerUI(this IApplicationBuilder app)
            => app
                .UseSwagger()
                .UseSwaggerUI(options =>
                {
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Your API");
                    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
                });

        public static void ApplyMigrations(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            using var services = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();

            var dbContext = services.ServiceProvider.GetService<YourDbContext>();

            dbContext.Database.Migrate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it in this package: **[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/)**

It's an extension declared here [RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions?view=efcore-7.0)

Answer (score -2):

In the constructor of your `DataContext` class you can use

```
this.Database.Migrate();
```

and it should do just fine.

Comment: Please read the question. That's exactly what they do, so it's all but "just fine".